# How to attach api_key to query parameters for Google Spreadsheet API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

This is what I do:

```
    let apikey = "my_api_key"
    let spreadsheetId = "my_spread_sheet_id"
    let range = "Class Data!A2:E"
    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:range)
    service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
```

but the error is following:

> The request is missing a valid API key.

How can I add that key?

Comment: Rather than use API_KEY in making API requests, I would suggest using OAuth2 instead to authorize the request. There's an instruction in the [Standard Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/query-parameters) docs. With exception to Maps, I noticed that Google API tend to be faulty when using API key instad of OAuth2. There's a [Swift Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) for starting reference.